# decimal value gives error

Tags: c#, decimal

I have a problem with decimal input, here is the code I'm using on Button click

```
private void button6_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string PName = "كريب دجاج شاورما";
        string PPrice = "20.50";
        string PQty = "1";

        textBox1.Text = PName;
        textBox6.Text = PPrice;
        textBox2.Text = PQty;
        textBox5.Text = "0";
    }

    private void button7_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string PName = "كريب تشيكن شريمبو";
        string PPrice = "28";
        string PQty = "1";

        textBox1.Text = PName;
        textBox6.Text = PPrice;
        textBox2.Text = PQty;
        textBox5.Text = "0";
    }
```

the one with PPrice 20.50 when click it shows Invalid Value in the textbox6
when the second one with the PPrice 28 clicked, it continues normally

how can I fix that so it would accept decimals?

**UPDATE**

the previous code wasn't the problem, the real problem is with this code, it shows the error when calculations are made not on textbox itself so here is the full code

```
private void button6_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string PName = "كريب دجاج شاورما";
        string PPrice = "20.50";
        string PQty = "1";

        textBox1.Text = PName;
        textBox6.Text = PPrice;
        textBox2.Text = PQty;
        textBox5.Text = "0";
    }

    private void button7_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string PName = "كريب تشيكن شريمبو";
        string PPrice = "28";
        string PQty = "1";

        textBox1.Text = PName;
        textBox6.Text = PPrice;
        textBox2.Text = PQty;
        textBox5.Text = "0";
    } private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Multiply();
    }

    private void textBox6_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int first = 0;
        int second = 0;
        if (Int32.TryParse(textBox5.Text, out second) && Int32.TryParse(textBox6.Text, out first))
            textBox3.Text = (first + second).ToString();
    }

    private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int first = 0;
        int second = 0;
        if (Int32.TryParse(textBox5.Text, out second) && Int32.TryParse(textBox6.Text, out first))
            textBox3.Text = (first + second).ToString();
    }
```

Comment: What type of textBox6 is?

Comment: This is not about showing "decimals" because in both cases the value assigned to the `.Text` is a string. Please slowly debug and really see that the expected function is called. Also when you say "invalid value" what do you mean?

Comment: Ok, clicking button, information goes to textboxes except for the decimal one gives "Invalid", then button clicked to add them to listview and here is what I get in debugging
An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Ok, very stupid of me, that isn't where the problem occurs, I will update now with the code that the problem happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are trying to convert string with decimal points to an integer.

You have this code:

```
string PPrice = "20.50";
textBox6.Text = PPrice;
```

Then you have this code:

```
int first = 0;
int second = 0;
if (Int32.TryParse(textBox5.Text, out second) && Int32.TryParse(textBox6.Text, out first))
            textBox3.Text = (first + second).ToString();
```

The `Int.TryParse(textbox6.Text, out first` fails and returns a `false` because `20.50` cannot be converted to an `integer`.

You need to parse the value to decimal and if it succeeds, then continue:

```
decimal pPrice;

if (decimal.TryParse(textbox6.Text, out pPrice))
{
    // do what you need 
}
else
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks, tested and it works great, solved me problem